# Binary representation of a number in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I came across this code for the binary representation of a number. I want to know the need for using !! in the code.

```
int main() {
    int n,i;
    unsigned flag = 1<<(sizeof(int) * 8 - 1);     

    printf("Input the number\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);     
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(int)*8;i++) {    
            printf("%d",!!(n & flag) );    
            n = n << 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flag used has only the MSB set and all other bits cleared, so that when you `bitwise and` it with number you can test the MSB in the number.

There are two outcomes of the bitwise anding:

- Zero - means the number had 0 in its
  MSB.
- Non-Zero - means the number had 1 in
  its MSB.

Now we need a way to map

```
Non-zero -> 1
Zero -> 0
```

so we use the double negation.

The same thing could have been done using:

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof(int)*8;i++) {

    (n & flag) ? printf("1"):printf("0");
    n = n << 1;
}
```

Comment: alternately, `printf(((n & flag) ? "1" : "0"));`

Answer (score 10):

`!!` will convert any non-zero value to 1, and leave zero value as zero.

```
x = 0;
y = 50;
!x; // 1
!y; // 0
!!x; // 0
!!y; // 1
```

It is a poor man's bool cast.

Comment: In some implementations of C, it'll be 0 or -1 rather than 0 or 1.

Comment: Not if the implementation is standards compliant. According to the current draft standard 6.3.1.2, "When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1."

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: No.  Logical operators are guaranteed to evaluate to 0 or 1.  Specifically: "The result of logical negation is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0." (6.5.3.3/5 of the C99 standard)

Answer (score 2):

I would write `!!x` less confusingly as `x != 0`.